# init a COO matrix from its attributes (data,row,col)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sparse-matrix

I have a script that computes the three attributes of the COO format:

```
data    COO format data array of the matrix
row     COO format row index array of the matrix
col     COO format column index array of the matrix
```

And i want to use these three arrays to initialise a coo_matrix() in order to use the methods available to the coo_matrix class. What would be the fastest way to do that without changing the main script?

Answer (score 0):

[`scipy.sparse` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix)

```
coo_matrix((data, (row, column)), [shape=(M, N)])
```

Comment: Doesn't work, and i think it needs the row,col, data of the dense matrix (+zeros)

Comment: And i get a syntax error at shape with the example : row=col = [0,1,2,3,4,5] and data = [1,2,3,1,4,5], M=N=6